# Software auto gen document on Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have a project which was designed by SOAP. It was opened on eclipse.
I would like to use a software for auto generate a document(html file) for developer tutorial .
It was generated by comment on above function.

Thanks,

Comment: it probably uses doxygen

Comment: If you want to write a developer tutorial, just write it.  Auto-generated documentation usually don't result in good tutorials--just a different view of the full source code.  Do your users a favor and write them something nice and succinct by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Use oxygen as stefan already said, it's free and you can get it here: http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html

> Generate documentation from source code
>
> Doxygen is the de facto standard tool for generating documentation
>   from annotated C++ sources, but it also supports other popular
>   programming languages such as C, Objective-C, C#, PHP, Java, Python,
>   IDL (Corba, Microsoft, and UNO/OpenOffice flavors), Fortran, VHDL,
>   Tcl, and to some extent D.
>
> Doxygen can help you in three ways:
>
> It can generate an on-line documentation browser (in HTML) and/or an
>   off-line reference manual (in ) from a set of documented source files.
>   There is also support for generating output in RTF (MS-Word),
>   PostScript, hyperlinked PDF, compressed HTML, and Unix man pages. The
>   documentation is extracted directly from the sources, which makes it
>   much easier to keep the documentation consistent with the source code.
>   You can configure doxygen to extract the code structure from
>   undocumented source files. This is very useful to quickly find your
>   way in large source distributions. Doxygen can also visualize the
>   relations between the various elements by means of include dependency
>   graphs, inheritance diagrams, and collaboration diagrams, which are
>   all generated automatically. You can also use doxygen for creating
>   normal documentation (as I did for the doxygen user manual and
>   web-site). Doxygen is developed under Mac OS X and Linux, but is
>   set-up to be highly portable. As a result, it runs on most other Unix
>   flavors as well. Furthermore, executables for Windows are available.